# node-mysql connection.query() returns undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, return, undefined, node-mysql

I'm using a node ws server built on [einaros/ws](https://github.com/einaros/ws).
That server has to send queries to a database. For that i'm using [felixge/node-mysql](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql).

When a user connects to the server, it should be checked if the client still exists in the database.

Here is the interesting piece of code:

```
console.log("client-liste ist leer");
var query = "SELECT name FROM spieler WHERE name='"+id+"' AND passwort='"+passwort+"'";
var result = queryToDatabase(query);
console.log(getTime() + "DB-Result Abfrage: " + result);
```

And the Code where the query is done:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var mysqlConnection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: dbHost,
    user: dbUser,
    password: dbPassword,
});

function queryToDatabase(anfrage) {
    mysqlConnection.connect();

mysqlConnection.query("USE " + db, function(err, rows, fields) {
    if (err) throw err;
});

mysqlConnection.query(anfrage, function(err, rows, fields) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log("rows as String - " + JSON.stringify(rows));
        return rows;

    });

    mysqlConnection.end();
}
```

The Logs in the console are:

client-liste ist leer 
3.8.2012 - 15:29:0 - DB-Result Abfrage: undefined
rows as String - [{"name":"lukas"}]

Does anyone understand, why the function returns undefined?
I also tried to wait for Database-Connection to finish with a simple setTimout, but nothing changed!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't return a value from an asynchronous callback like the one used by `query`. You need to rewrite queryToDatabase so it takes a callback as its second argument and calls it with `rows` when the query is successful. Then your main code needs to look like:

```
queryToDatabase(query, function(result) {
     console.log(getTime() + "DB-Result Abfrage: " + result);
   });
```

In reality, all your code that depends on the query result will need to go into that callback.

In practice, you'd want the callback to take two arguments: an **error status** and a **result**, with the error status being `null` if the query was successful.